# Replace Doxygen detaileddescription tags with HTML tags

Tags: html, xml, documentation, doxygen

I'm generating a XML documentation using Doxygen. I'm formatting my descriptions with Markdown and I'm perplexed that the tags that are in between the "detaileddescription" tag are not HTML tags. For example.

```
<heading level="1">Example</heading>
```

I checked the configuration file of Oxygen to see if it possible to force it to generate HTML tags instead of the custom ones. I also Googled to see if someone had the same problem, but nothing.

Do you see a solution to this problem I should i just write a converter by myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While (in theory) doxygen could have produced XHTML for the documentation blocks inside the XML output, it does not do so.

So yes it is a different format and if you need HTML you will need to translate it.

Reasons behind this.

- Flexibility: If someone wants to produce another output format, starting from XHTML would be more difficult than using the same internal representation that doxygen itself uses to produce all output formats.
- Legacy: Doxygen already produced XML before there was a XML compliant standard for HTML (i.e. XHTML)

Comment: In this case i would like to recommend the following change: save the description section in the XML file as is. So if i wrote the description using markdown i can grab it in converted. I hope this solution make sense to you. 

Best.